# CSS causes form to become unusable when window is less than 448px wide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Here's a fiddle that replicates the issue. You'll have to size the result window down so that it's less than 448px wide, but you'll see what I'm talking about when you do.

http://jsfiddle.net/kehlan/wqS82/

In Chrome's developer tools, this is the computed styling that's applied to the div containing the form, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8.15999984741211px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8.15999984741211px;
border-top-left-radius: 8.15999984741211px;
border-top-right-radius: 8.15999984741211px;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
height: 301.09375px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
width: 385px;
```

Could any CSS gurus help me out here? I need the form to retain its original styles regardless of the width of the window.

Comment: i would solve it via media queries.

Comment: I'm not that great with CSS, so that statement doesn't help me out much. @nevermind

Comment: i am not CSS pro, too, thats why i would use css media queries> http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ So, for screens lower than 450px -> apply set of special css rules. :)

Comment: But that's the opposite of what I need. I need *no special media rules.* I'm pretty sure jQueryMobile's CSS is causing the special rules to apply, and I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: @kehrk Do not resize window, if you don't want to use media queries :)  Made a quick mockup http://jsfiddle.net/wqS82/3/

Comment: I appreciate the effort. That said, I can't really express how little that helps my situation. @Morpheus

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wqS82/5/ Better?

Comment: Perhaps youre using the wrong UI framework. If you don't want a responsive UI, then jQueryMobile might not be the best choice. You can use Bootstrap without responsive, and you can achieve a similar look and feel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.

For some reason, a couple of `float` rules in the form caused the issue.

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kehlan/wqS82/6/